# How could a vampire survive being beheaded?

Tags: world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade

During [the first cutscene of the 2004 video game *Vampire: The Masquerade — Bloodlines*](https://youtu.be/FvvLJemwTZY) the sire of the protagonist is beheaded. However, some parts of the plot tell me that his/her death could be actually just faked, and I was interested:

**How can a vampire fake their own death and surviving being beheaded?**

Remember that the protagonist of *VtM:B* (and hence his sire) can only be from one of the standard Camarilla clans: Brujah, Gangrel, Malkavian, Noferatu, Toreador, Tremere, Ventrue. I would prefer an answer that is normally available to one of those clans.

Edition from which the answer comes from doesn't matter, but it has to be available to Kindred.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While there are ways as others have said to fake a beheading, as far as I can tell, there are very few ways to survive an actual *successful* beheading.

The most likely to potentially survive are the **Tzmisce** and the **Tremere** but only one who is very, *very* skilled and clever and has had prior time to prepare for the event of a beheading. Which I suppose the VtM:B sire might well have had.

This is how it could be done:

**Vicissitude**: A Tzmisce with enough skill, could probably move their brain to not actually being where you would expect it to be, with how much mastery they have over their own bodies. They can also inflict this on others - for instance, Malgorzata was a non-Tzmisce kindred that found herself hideously tortured and warped by them. Other vampires eventually discovered her and tried to mercy kill her, but had a difficulty finding where her actual brain was to chop off.

I imagine a more subtle version of this could be employed too than full-scale obvious warping.

This would not apply to the protagonist's sire however, as they cannot be Tzmisce: *unless* you want to believe that the to-be-sire pulled a *very* dark favour some point somewhere and had someone else do it for them.

**Tremere ritual:** A tremere regent/primogen named Hannah, canonically survived an assassination attempt by "simply" putting her soul elsewhere from the body which was destroyed.

> Later, it is revealed that Hannah actually survived the assassination attempt by migrating her spirit into a statue

Hannah was 7th generation too: and as the player's sire must have been 7th as well (by virtue of their childe being 8th), then there is more of a chance of them being powerful enough to also successfully pull something like this off.

There's also some Tremere who even pull a "grand theft me" and body snatch somebody - although that has been extremely rare as far as I can tell.

The only examples I know of off the top of my head - although others may feel free to correct me - are 4th generation kindred hijacking other vampires in their clan...but if a 7th gen can put their soul in a statue they might be able to perhaps hijack a weak-willed *mortal* or something along those lines. Perhaps a pre-prepared ghoul if it requires a bloodline connection.

Although I have to admit there's little specific information on that, at least that I've been able to find anyway, unfortunately.

Answer (score 9):

## Option A.

**Dominate 3:** The Forgetful mind. (Tremere, Ventrue)

With the ability to re-write memories any sort of witness statements become controllable and rewritable, as what they remember what you want.

Example;

Bob the Neonate is determined to kill Fred the Elder and busts into his lair with a greatsword. However instead he finds another vampire, Emma. Emma and Bob fight and Bob chops off Emma's head. Bob curses and leaves the room as Emma turns into dust.

At this point Fred emerges from the shadows and uses Dominate 3: Forgetful mind on Bob, changing Bob's memories to think that instead he chopped off Fred's head. Fred then slinks back into the shadows as Bob goes off to celebrate killing an Elder.

## Option B.

For the cutscene; a combination of things could be used:

1. Find a vampire patsy with Obfuscate 3 - Mask of a thousand faces OR use Obfuscate 5 (Cloak the gathering) to use Obfuscate 3 on the patsy to make them look like you.
2. Dominate (Notice my favourite discipline?) Mesmerise (2) or Conditioning (4) -more likely the second - the patsy to go quietly for the execution and think they're you.
3. Let the patsy be captured impersonating you and watch them get executed, for bonus points disguise yourself as them via Obfuscate while it's happening.

Note: With non-Camarilla clans you have Chimerstry which can be used for all kinds of fun.

Comment: There is no reason to sacrifice Emma, as Fred could just fake memories of killing Fred. And this wouldn't work in public, too many people to work with -- I have added a link to the game's cutscene. Interesting addition, however.

Comment: True; but offing Emma leaves us with a pile of vampire dust and wounds on Bob for secondary evidence.

Comment: This does not answer the actual question "how could a vampire survive being beheaded".

Comment: For non Cami, you can add vicissitude (2 and/or 3) to turn an other guy to a clone of you+ dominate (2,4 or 5) to make him react as you could